# Bootstrap 4 - Are Grunt and NPM required?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Can Bootstrap 4 be used just by adding the references to the Bootstrap libraries in the header (like in Bootstrap 3)?

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Are Grunt and NPM needed if not using any of the JavaScript plugins? All the Bootstrap 4 tutorials I have seen start in about installing Grunt and NPM which I am not interested in.

Comment: No, they're not required. You can simply use the dist CSS and JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not required if you do not need to modify Bootstrap.

Grunt and NPM are used for compiling the javascript and css.
If you want to e.g. edit the Bootstrap source code or include bootstrap in your own scss, you will probably need Grunt and NPM.